# Powerline hub speed limitation

Tags: powerline-networking

I'm planning on installing 3 Powerline AV2 adapters in my home (I'm located in Italy) to be able to stream games to my TV set through a Steam link. One powerline for internet connection, one to the PC, one to the TV set. The powerline adapters have a theoretical speed of 1000Mbps and should be fit for the job. The wiring itself is pretty new. 
One powerline adapter will be connected to the modem/router for internet connectivity. The modem/router has LAN ports limited to 100Mbits. 
Will the modem/router speed limitation limit the speed of all the other devices connected to the powerline circuit, or will they be able to operate at the theoretical speed of 1000Mbits?

Comment: I think they will be limited.  However, some computers can use two or more ethernet lines in parallel.  I think it is called dual LAN.

Comment: The core PowerLine speed will not be limited by a slow client somewhere. Personally, I haven't made any good experience with Powerline data transmission, though. I recommend you conduct some _iperf_ tests of significant duration.

Comment: @chris: Nope. It is not calle dual LAN. Dual LAN is just a marketing term to indicate that it has two network cards.  What you probably are looking for is 'multi-homed' (using multiple network card at the same time) or 'bonded/teamed' (using two links as one faster link).

Comment: If the modem is limited to 100 Mbits then the network created by the Powerline adapters will be limited to 100 Mbits when accessing any device outside of your network.  The intranet speed will be limited to 1 Gbits though, which means, any device within your network.  Easy enough to solve this bottlekneck though.

Comment: Any of the "AV2" adapters have a max throughout of 500Mbps.  They use a 1000Mbps link speed, but 500 is the "max theoretical speed".  So, in the real world, you might see 125 Mbps.

Answer (score 0):

Communication between the powerlines will be at up to 1000Mbit/sec.

```
Powerline 1 =---+
                |
Powerline 2 =---+         <--- Theroretical 1000Mbit
                |
Powerline 3 =---+
    |
    |                      <--- 100mbit
    |
Switch in the router
```

In powerline 1 can talk to powerlines 2 and 3 at speeds up to 1000Mbit/sec and vice versa.  But communication to and from the router is limited to 100Mbit/sec. This only limits the speed for this one connection.

Note that communication the other other side of the modem is obviously also limited to 100mbit since it needs to pass though ythe router.

If it helps think of it as three thick pipes and one thinner pipe.

Comment: As someone who has used homeplug a fair bit, the practical speed is ~ 1/3 what's listed. The rest of this seems pretty correct

Comment: Aye. Hence all the careful 'up to' and 'theoretical'.  I do try to keep the answers short and simple. But I suspect that the OP already knew that from the careful use of his/her wording.

Comment: Indeed. So I guess in a "streaming game setting" it would be reasonable to suppose that the "thin pipe" will give me the ping to the game server (Rocket league) while the "thick pipes" should determine the A/V data stream speed PC->Steam Link->TV.

Comment: Aye. Ping times are sometimes a nice indicator of performance, but note ping alone does not say anythhing about speed. a 1Mbit line may ping faster than a 1000Mbit line.